# Is there a dash like feature in lubuntu, so I can easily search everything?

Tags: lubuntu, unity-dash, search

Is there a dash like program in lubuntu that can be launched either by single or double Super tap. I would want to search, and be able to see a lit of all my apps, preferably in icon form, like the dash. However, I would be happy if it didn't have all the features of the dash, and was more like the [OSX Launchpad](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5548), which is simply an application launcher.

Whenever I switch to my lubuntu machine, I miss the ease of access to all my programs.

If there is not, what is the key to open the "Start" menu?

Comment: You have several options. Personally I advise dmenu - See https://urukrama.wordpress.com/category/dmenu/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen How does that create a dash feature? Sorry, I might just be being slow here...

Comment: I suppose it depends on what features you want.